# Vaadin: Force CSS-containers to fit full width after animation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vaadin, vaadin7

I am developing with Vaadin 7 and wanted to create a sidebar, which can be toggled visible via button click. The sidebar-container appears / disappears with a CSS rotation animation and folds to the right.

All the components are placed in `CSSLayouts` and organized like this (Every container represents one Layout-object):

[image]

I want the `mainContainer` to take the full width of the `root`-container when the sidebar is toggled invisible. My problem is that the `sidebarContainer` only shows up if I give it a static width (e.g. 300px). When invisible, a white blank space remains where the sidebar used to be.

Here some pictures showing my idea of the result:

[image: Sidebar toggled visible]

[image: Sidebar toggled invisible]

My orientation was the [Vaadin Sampler](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/), where the menu Button unfolds a sidebar and the main content gets moved to the left. Which possibilities exist to realize such a smooth container resizing animation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to solve the problem with a combination of styling and Java code.

The button click event resizes the `.sidebarContainer` cssLayout. When the sidebar is toggled invisible, the layout `width` is set to `0`.
The sidebar container adapts two animation CSS classes for the opening and closing animations, which are also directed by the button click event.

**Java**

```
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

    if (sidebar.getStyleName().contains("sidebar-in"))
    {
        sidebar.removeStyleName("sidebar-in");
        sidebar.setStyleName("sidebar-out");
        sidebarContainer.setWidth(0,Unit.PIXELS);
        return;
    }

    sidebar.removeStyleName("sidebar-out");
    sidebar.setStyleName("sidebar-in");
    sidebarContainer.setWidth(300,Unit.PIXELS);
}
```

To let the `.mainContainer` shift as smoothly as in the Vaadin sampler application, I gave the `.sidebarContainer` a transition attribute. Now, when this container is resized by the button click event, the CSS ease-function creates a width-changing movement and the flex-layout of the `mainContainer` makes it stick to that movement. The sidebar itself is a panel inside the `.sidebarContainer`.

**CSS**

```
.mainContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
    width: auto;
}

.sidebarContainer { 
    order: 2;   
    transition: width 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
}

.sidebar-in{
   animation: sidebarAnimationFramesIn ease 1s;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   transform-origin: 100% 50%;
   animation-fill-mode:forwards;
   width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-out{
   animation: sidebarAnimationFramesOut ease 1s;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   transform-origin: 100% 50%;
   animation-fill-mode:forwards;
   width: 100%;
}
```

I realized the toggle-animation of the sidebar by adding Keyframes in CSS

Comment: Nice. This might come in handy!

Answer (score 0):

The good and the bad of a CSSPanel is that it is a white table, where everything can be done, but still needs to be write (like css styling and such).
I can suggesto to take a look at HorizontalSplitPanel where you should block and hide the separator. It should listen perfectly when you decide to collapse a side.
I havent tasted it right now on your use case but i have used before and never had an issue. Give it a go!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to use a HorizontalSplitPanel before and this worked fine for a static moving of the separator position. Unfortunately I didn't figure out how to insert an animation in that case. I didn't like the fact that I had to dictate the separator position by the button click event.